How to set up an ATH chart in Tradingview
I watched a YouTube video where the presenter displayed a chart of Nvidia's all-time high (ATH) levels. The chart was configured to depict the stock's historical ATH levels as the maximum points, this setup allows viewers to see how the current stock price compares to its highest historical points, how is this done?

